# mysql table insert error

Tags: php

hi guys thanks for time.
am getting a mysql error  here is my php code used

```
if(isset($_POST["content_txt"]) && strlen($_POST["content_txt"])>0) 
{   //check $_POST["content_txt"] is not empty

    //sanitize post value, PHP filter FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH Strip tags, encode special characters.
    $contentToSave = filter_var($_POST["content_txt"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); 

    // Insert sanitize string in record
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO f_add_course(content) VALUES('".$contentToSave."')");

    if($insert_row)
    {
         //Record was successfully inserted, respond result back to index page
          $my_id = $mysqli->insert_id; //Get ID of last inserted row from MySQL
          echo '<li id="item_'.$my_id.'">';
          echo '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$my_id.'">';
          echo '<img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />';
          echo '</a></div>';
          echo $contentToSave.'</li>';
          $mysqli->close(); //close db connection

    }else{

        //header('HTTP/1.1 500 '.mysql_error()); //display sql errors.. must not output sql errors in live mode.
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
        exit();
    }
```

and its not inserting the data

```
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO f_add_course(content) VALUES('".$contentToSave."')");

if($insert_row)
```

its skipping the if condition and no data is inserted into table hank in advance

Comment: And what might that error be?

Comment: If you are getting an error then you should probably post the error.

Comment: its skipping the if condition and no data is inserted into table

Comment: echo your sql query and directly run it in mysql query browser

Comment: There may be an issue with quotes (single / double ) in the query you are executing. Please print this query and check for its correctness.

Comment: Are You sure your connection is Correct, I think you should check your connection first and then debug next.

Comment: For debugging purposes, run the following in the query window/phpmyadmin and see what gets printed out `INSERT INTO f_add_course(content) VALUES('testing content');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check a sample query here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

seems you need to change the query execution to:

```
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO f_add_course (content) 
VALUES("'.$contentToSave.'")");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a space between `f_add_course` and `(content)` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["content_txt"]) && strlen($_POST["content_txt"])>0){   
    //check $_POST["content_txt"] is not empty
    //sanitize post value, PHP filter FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH Strip tags, encode special characters.
    $contentToSave = filter_var($_POST["content_txt"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); 
    // Insert sanitize string in record
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO f_add_course(content) VALUES('$contentToSave')");
    if($insert_row){
        //Record was successfully inserted, respond result back to index page
        $my_id = $mysqli->insert_id; //Get ID of last inserted row from MySQL
        echo '<li id="item_'.$my_id.'">';
        echo '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$my_id.'">';
        echo '<img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />';
        echo '</a></div>';
        echo $contentToSave.'</li>';
        $mysqli->close(); //close db connection
    } else {
        //header('HTTP/1.1 500 '.mysql_error()); //display sql errors.. must not output sql errors in live mode.
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```